# Apache RewriteRule second internal redirect not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have multiple virtual servers - meaning same domain name with multiple ports like 1234, 5678, 7890, etc and same code base. Below are the details:

Domain: `www.whatever:1234.com`

Folders: `/fool/`, `/foo2/`, `/foo3/`

```
foo1/.htaccess:

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /foo2/$1 [L]


foo2/.htaccess:

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^blah$ /foo3/a.html [L,R=301]
```

Now, the expected behaviour is:

`www.whatever.com:1234/foo1/blah` redirects to `www.whatever.com:1234/foo3/a.html`,

Whereas in reality I see it as:

`www.whatever.com:1234/foo1/blah` redirects to `www.whatever.com/foo3/a.html`

Port number is stripped !!

Whereas, if I place `R=301` in the `foo1/.htaccess`, then there are two redirections like:

`www.whatever.com:1234/foo1/blah` redirects to `www.whatever.com:1234/foo2/blah` and again
redirects to `www.whatever.com:1234/foo3/a.html`

But I don't want the user to see two redirections. Also, I don't want to hardcode the hostname in foo2/.htaccess, as I have same code base across different virtual servers.

I tried PT option in `foo1/.htaccess`, but that didn't work. So, can you please help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

foo2/.htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^blah$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}:${SERVER_PORT}/foo3/a.html [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Hello Anubhava, forgot to mention the main reason is that I have different virtual servers like :1234, :4567, :8901 and same code base. So, I can't hardcode the domain name. Thanks, I'll edit the question.

Comment: hmm... yeah, this will work, but was wondering why would the port number is stripped? Any idea on that?

Comment: If it works then use it. Apache doesn't maintain all the states between multiple internal and external rewires.